# ajax call is not working with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

i am creating a blog just for practice and i want to mark all notifications as seen when the user view the notifications, this is working if i go to the url but when i use ajax nothing happen

javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#testb").click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'seen' request.user.username %}",
             success: function(){
                 confirm('it worked')
             }
        });
        return false;
   });

});
</script>
```

url 
`url(r'functions/user/(?P<username>\w+)/seen', views.seen, name='seen')`

view:

```
def seen(request, username):
    nat = Nat.objects.filter(toUser=username)
    nat.update(show=False)
    return HttpResponse("test")
```

Comment: Open your browser's debugging tools.  What is the actual `url` value in the client-side code?  Is there an error on the development console?  Is the JavaScript code executed at all?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: thank you for the response, the url is right, django server console not showing any activity at the *seen url*

Comment: `"the url is right"` - Are you *assuming* that, or have you *confirmed* that through debugging?  When you perform that debugging, what are the answers to the variety of other questions asked in the comment above?

Comment: maybe csrf on data post is needed.
first get the csrf: "csrf = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();". After send on data parameter on ajax.
$.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf},
             ...        
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@csrf_exempt
def seen(request, username):
    if request.method=='POST':
        nat = Nat.objects.filter(toUser=username)
        nat.update(show=False)
        return JsonResponse("test":"json response")
```

Try this, it is not safe for production but as you said, for just training is useful.

Comment: docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax In the Ajax section is explained what you have to add to the code. Then you also have to add a field in $.ajax in this way `data:{csrftoken},`